# Java: saving image as JPEG skew problem

Tags: java, c++, jpeg, padding, skew

I am trying to save an image to JPEG. The code below works fine when image width is a multiple of 4, but the image is skewed otherwise. It has something to do with padding. When I was debugging I was able to save the image as a bitmap correctly, by padding each row with 0s. However, this did not work out with the JPEG.

Main point to remember is my image is represented as bgr (blue green red 1 byte each) byte array which I receive from a native call.

```
byte[] data = captureImage(OpenGLCanvas.getLastFocused().getViewId(), x, y);
if (data.length != 3*x*y)
{
  // 3 bytes per pixel
  return false;
}

// create buffered image from raw data
DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(data, 3*x*y);
ComponentSampleModel csm = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, x, y, 3, 3*x, new int[]{0,1,2} );
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(csm, buffer, new Point(0,0));
BufferedImage buff_image = new BufferedImage(x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR); // because windows goes the wrong way...
buff_image.setData(raster);

//save the BufferedImage as a jpeg
try
{
  File file = new File(file_name);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

  JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
  JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(buff_image);
  param.setQuality(1.0f, false);
  encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
  encoder.encode(buff_image);
  out.close();
  // or JDK 1.4
  // ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", out);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Write permissions on "file_name"
  return false;
}
```

I also looked on creating the JPEG in C++ but there was even less material on that, but it is still an option.

Any help greatly apprecieated.
Leon

Comment: A link to example output could be really helpful

Comment: resolution width with a multiple of 4 http://tinypic.com/r/2zqd547/7  and resolution width NOT a multiple of 4 http://tinypic.com/r/6i49pw/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, but I have managed to work it out.

To capture the image I was using WINGDIAPI HBITMAP WINAPI CreateDIBSection in C++, then OpenGL would draw to that bitmap. Unbeknown to be, there was padding added to the bitmap automatically the width was not a multiple of 4.

Therefore Java was incorrectly interpreting the byte array.

Correct way is to interpret bytes is

```
byte[] data = captureImage(OpenGLCanvas.getLastFocused().getViewId(), x, y);
int x_padding = x%4;
BufferedImage buff_image = new BufferedImage(x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int val;
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
  {
    val =  ( data[(i + j*x)*3 + j*x_padding + 2]& 0xff) + 
           ((data[(i + j*x)*3 + j*x_padding + 1]& 0xff) << 8) +
           ((data[(i + j*x)*3 + j*x_padding + 0]& 0xff) << 16);
    buff_image.setRGB(i, j, val);
  }
}

//save the BufferedImage as a jpeg
try
{
  File file = new File(file_name);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

  JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
  JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(buff_image);
  param.setQuality(1.0f, false);
  encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
  encoder.encode(buff_image);
  out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JPEG standard is extremely complex. I am thinking it may be an issue with padding the output of the DCT somehow. The DCT is done to transform the content from YCrCb 4:2:2 to signal space with one DCT for each channel, Y,Cr, and Cb. The DCT is done on a "Macroblock" or "minimum coded block" depending on your context. JPEG usually has 8x8 macroblocks. When on the edge and there are not enough pixel it clamps the edge value and "drags it across" and does a DCT on that.

I am not sure if this helps, but it sounds like a non standard conforming file. I suggest you use [JPEGSnoop](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html) to find out more. There are also several explanations about how JPEG compression works.

One possibility is that the sample rate may be encoded incorrectly. It might be something exotic such as 4:2:1 So you might be pulling twice as many X samples as there really are, thus distorting the image.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it does not really help me. This is not a file, it is an image I capture from the screen and it is store as a byte array

Comment: I interpreted "I am trying to save an image to JPEG" as saving a file. If you have a JPEG byte array, then you hopefully have a library to decode the binary stream.

Answer (score 0):

> it is an image I capture from the screen

Maybe the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class will be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was not completely clear about screen capture. The 'image' is captured by getting OpenGL to draw into a buffer (bitmap) in C++. This 24bit bitmap I want to save as a Jpeg for compression